# How to achieve React app with subdomain structure?

Tags: reactjs, subdomain

I am a bit confused about how subdomains work with React apps and the best practices involved. I am trying to attain the following structure:

- Parent App -- https://parentapp.com (React app)
- Child App  -- https://app.parentapp.com (React app)

With the parent app serving as a static page designed to display information about the child app (button which takes users to the child app). Basically, what I am trying to do is have the parent be a company site itself and the child app be a specific product of that company.

Now, what I am confused about is how the actual React apps should be organized. Should they both be in one project? Or should they be two completely separate projects where the actual routing is handled by the hosting service? What is the ideal way to organize such a structure?

Comment: FYI on Stack Overflow, backtick quotes are for bits of code, not highlighting names of products.

Comment: It's not clear from your question about what is the "parent/child" relationship between these two apps.  What do they have in common, and what do they need to have separate?  Also please indicate which Firebase products you're using.  Firebase is a pretty big platform with over a dozen different products.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited it for clarity

Comment: Removed the firebase tag since this question isn't really about Firebase.